# Angular PreRendering / Ng Universal deployment

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, server-side-rendering

Is it *really* necessary to copy the node_modules upon deploy?   What is normally a 7 minute compile/run unit tests/deploy to the staging environment becomes a 40 minute process due to the 840 node modules we've got (running Angular 7 + Material + Ng-Select).  The issue comes down to system I/O of the nearly 100k tiny files.

I'm trying to figure out a way to keep SSR, but it's becoming a losing battle when developers are waiting most of an hour to see their changes in the staging environment.

Is there a way to bundle and minify the node modules into the main.server.ts file, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You should only have to move the `/dist` folder contents to your deploy area.
Depending on the version of Universal, a `/dist/server` and `/dist/browser` should be generated with the needed contents.

The `server.js` that's produced is normally rather large as it contains most of your application **and needed dependencies** for use in the rendering process.

For instance, this is a quick'n'dirty example Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./dist /app/dist
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["node", "/app/server"]
```

Note I left the target directory as `dist` -- if changing this folder, I believe the matching change needs done in `server.ts`:

```
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/{app}/browser');
```

It looks at `/dist` relative to where the current working directory (`WORKDIR`) was when starting the node process.